# Assembly plugin does not substitute maven properties

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am attempting to get the maven assembly plugin to automatically add the Documentation
to the final ZIP file for the product. The POM file looks like this:

```
<!-- Build configuration. -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Assembly plugin. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <includeProjectArtifact>false</includeProjectArtifact>
              <archiveBaseDirectory>/</archiveBaseDirectory>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Deploy plugin. 
           This artifact needs to be deployed.
           -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The assembly.xml looks like this:

```
<assembly 
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

  <!-- Archive details. -->
  <id>fullzipfile</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <!-- Component descriptors. -->
  <componentDescriptors>
    <componentDescriptor>assembly-gdbserver.xml</componentDescriptor>
    <componentDescriptor>assembly-gdbws.xml</componentDescriptor>
    <componentDescriptor>assembly-gothic.xml</componentDescriptor>
    <componentDescriptor>assembly-resources.xml</componentDescriptor>
    <componentDescriptor>assembly-weblogic.xml</componentDescriptor>
    <componentDescriptor>assembly-docs.xml</componentDescriptor>
  </componentDescriptors>
</assembly>
```

and the assembly-docs.xml looks like this:

```
<component
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/component-1.1.2.xsd">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/Documentation</directory>
      <outputDirectory>Documentation</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</component>
```

The only way I have got this to work is to replace the ${basedir} with the actual full
path to the Documentation directory on my machine. This will not work in our CI
environment. I have also tried ${project.basedir}.

At this time nothing is put into the Documentation directory in my ZIP. None of the 3
PDF files present in the directory is copied.

Comment: Where is the "Documentation" directory located ?

Comment: In the basedir of the project. In the same directory as the pom.xml.

Comment: Just try to use `<directory>Documentation</directory>` in your component descriptor. If this does not work remove the `<archiveBaseDirectory>/</archiveBaseDirectory>` in your maven-assembly-plugin configuration and check further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removal of the following line in the pom.xml

```
<archiveBaseDirectory>/</archiveBaseDirectory>
```

fixes the problem. Not sure why, but it does.